# Where do I find the "Enable Agent → Master Access Control" option in jenkins config on file system?

Tags: jenkins, docker-swarm

I am setting up a jenkins service on docker swarm. In my image, I am shipping a basic configuration (incl. `config.xml`, `proxy.xml`, ...) for jenkins. I want the "Enable Agent → Master Access Control" option under "Configure global security" to be swithed on by default, so what do I have so set in which configuration file?

I started a jenkins service in my docker swarm without that switch, turned the option on via web interface and checked `${JENKINS_HOME}/config.xml` but I could not find anything in `config.xml` that sounds like the option I want.

The "Enable Agent → Master Access Control" option should be switched on via config file. Can anyone advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$JENKINS_HOME/secrets/slave-to-master-security-kill-switch` is the file you're looking for.

Excerpt from the [official doc](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Slave+To+Master+Access+Control):

There are essentially three ways of enabling the access control mechanism:

- Through web UI, go to http://jenkins/configureSecurity and check "Enable Agent → Master Access Control" option.
- Through file system, create or edit the file $JENKINS_HOME/secrets/slave-to-master-security-kill-switch so that it contains false.
- Using a Groovy Hook Script and doing something like this:

```
import jenkins.security.s2m.AdminWhitelistRule
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
Jenkins.instance.getInjector().getInstance(AdminWhitelistRule.class)
.setMasterKillSwitch(false)
```

Comment: great, thank you. I found about the Groovy Script when I googled but not about the file :-) Works perfectly

Comment: Thanks I tried the script on a `jenkins/jenkins:lts` docker container and it worked.